# How to convert DateTime value into Filename in J2ME

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

I am doing a Java mobile program using J2ME.

I want to save date time field value into a Mysql, I am trying to convert the datetime field into a long and saving it in Mysql if its possible.

In c# ToFileTime() method which does it, is there anything like that in J2ME??

```
  public DateField getDateField() {
        if (dateField == null) {
            // write pre-init user code here
            dateField = new DateField("dateField", DateField.DATE_TIME);
            dateField.setDate(new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            // write post-init user code here
            long myFileTime = dateField.
        }
        return dateField;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to correct 2 lines

```
//no need to pass system current time. new Date() creates current time date
 dateField.setDate(new java.util.Date());

// gettime returns time in millis
long myFileTime = dateField.getDate().getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. And if I wanted to convert it back to and set the datefield back how will I achieve that?

Comment: `Date d2 = new Date(myFileTime);`